# Configure his web server with DNS domain

Tags: networking, dns, noip

I bought a Raspberry Pi 3 model B+ few days ago in order to set a web server. I have a web application (Django framework) with gunicorn + nginx server application.

I'm the worst noobie with network domain !

Today, I bought a domain name on Gandi (https://www.gandi.net/en) : **www.astrophoto-val.fr**

Then, I bought a DyDNS account on No-IP (https://www.noip.com/) and I added my domain name from Gandi.

Through this way, I can plug my Raspberry in my home and access from external network to my Raspberry thanks to DyDNS rules in my network router.

I configured Gandi Names Servers like this :

```
DNS1 : ns1.no-ip.com
DNS2 : ns2.no-ip.com
DNS3 : ns3.no-ip.com
DNS4 : ns4.no-ip.com
DNS5 : ns5.no-ip.com
```

And with No-IP in DNS Hosts/Redirects :

[image]

Is it correct or not at all ?

Comment: Seems fine, what exactly is the issue you are referring to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure there are no DNS issues, follow the below steps -

- On Domain registerar site (gandi.net) point the Name Servers to No-IP.com name servers (ns1.no-ip.com etc.)
- On no-ip dashboard, add the DNS zone file entries, add A record / cname record pointing to your no-ip.com provided url / ip address.
- Wait for the complete propagation to happen, things should be fine.

Comment: It's what I've done but I had an issue I wrote `ns4.noip.com` instead of `ns4.no-ip.com`..
In my question I wrote manually `DNS ...` and I didn't make any issue